# Question about using Bonjour or other methods to secure a connection with a non computer device

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi, router, bonjour

So I have a project I am working on, and I would basically like to send a basic yes/no command from the iPhone to a wifi enabled device that is also connectedto the network on the same router. This other device is not a computer, so I am wondering if I can still use Bonjour? In order to use Bonjour, do both of the communicating devices need to have some sort of a script installed and running that is allowing them to communicate? What would be the best way to connect to this device that is connected to the router, and then to send information/commands to it? I could really use some help finding a direction, because once I identify which tools I need to use, I can research them out and get it done (maybe). If anyone could offer any insight/suggestions whatsoever, it would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour is a local service discovery protocol based on multicast DNS. Even if your device supports it you still need some piece of software on the device to listen to your commands.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. After reading more documentation, I understand that bonjour can be used to connect to a device such as a printer. Does this mean that some sort of client software needs to be installed on the printer? I appreciate any insights you have to offer

Comment: Yes, basically bonjour/zeroconf is used to discover nodes and the services they provide on the local ether (wired or not) but then you still need the service itself running on the device, like IPP server on a printer. Something needs to accept and understand those IP packets :)